# Are the chances for all cards equal in YGO Power of Chaos (and the Expansions)

Tags: yu-gi-oh-power-of-chaos

I wonder if the chances for specific cards are lower or higher than others in Yu-Gi-Oh! Power of Chaos (any of the trilogy).

You get 3 cards after a BO3-match (if won) and in the 3 there will never be duplicates. (but you can of course collect more than 1 over the course of more matches)

Since there are 155/315 in the first 2 games the chances to get a specific card should be ~1:50 and 1:105 respectively.

But I I have my doubts that the RNG is flawless. (I hunt for a specific card to get 3 of them and already have almost all cards at 3, but this at 1 only)

I know I can just unlock all cards, but I want to play my way through.

So... are the chances equal? Can I influence what I get with what I play?

The card which I hunt is Elegant Egoist (to summon Harpie Lady Sisters)

Comment: While I'm not familiar with these games, it may be useful to know which specific card you are asking about.  Card games typically have different rarities, so some card will be less likely to be obtained.

Comment: Ah ok, I will edit the post